# Show img ALT text inside a div

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, alt

I'm using this code to show `img alt` inside show `div`. The problem is that it doesn't update at every `img` change.

Is there any different `addEventListener` that I can use so that it will change the alt at every visible image on the screen and without the need to click?

```
var myImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var text = document.getElementById("show");

for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
    myImage[i].addEventListener('click',show);
}

function show(){
    var myAlt = this.alt;
    text.innerHTML = myAlt;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the  `load` event.

Comment: @connexo that was very easy :) Thanks so much!

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to reference that text div by an id - remember id must be unique and you can have only one element with the `id="show"` on the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply iterate over the images as soon as the HTML is ready? Simply attach a single listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]')]

  for (const image of images) {
    const altDiv = document.createElement('div')
    altDiv.textContent = image.getAttribute('alt')
    image.parentNode.appendChild(altDiv)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="my beautiful alt text" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="my beautiful alt text 2" />
</div>
```

If you want to make sure the images are loaded before showing the alt text, do the showText magic on the `load` event of each image:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]')]

  for (const image of images) {
    image.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
      const altDiv = document.createElement('div')
      altDiv.textContent = image.getAttribute('alt')
      image.parentNode.appendChild(altDiv)
    })
  }

})
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="my beautiful alt text" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/" alt="my beautiful alt text 2" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="my beautiful alt text 3" />
</div>
```